# Значение вложенного enum (вложенного в Класс 1) необходимо передать в параметры конструктора Класса 2, где оба класса используют объекты друг друга

Tags: c++, ооп, inner, enum-class

В проекте присутствует 3 Файла:

- main.cpp (*в нём создаются объекты классов **A**, **B***)
- Class A.h (реализация класса **A** + реализация вложенного в класс A перечисления **Color**)
- Class B.h (реализация класса **B** + реализация вложенного в класс B перечисления **Site**)

В проекте присутствует проблема того, что Конструктор Класса A принимает в параметры - адрес памяти объекта класса B, значение вложенного enum[Site] Класса[B]. Адрес памяти объекта класса B он способен принять, а значение вложенного enum Класса

Конструктор класса A способен принимать в параметры указатель на объект класса B, но не его вложенные конструкции (например, как enum в данном примере). Иными словами, если убрать абсолютно всё, что связано с вложенными enum - проект скомпилируется.

Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы:

- Класс A смог использовать (увидеть) вложенный enum Класса B (enum class **Site**)?
- Класс B смог использовать (увидеть) вложенный enum Класса A (enum class **Color**)?

При всём этом, классы A и B используют объекты друг друга.

```
// main.cpp

#include "Class A.h"
#include "Class B.h"

int main()
{
    B objB((A*)nullptr, A::Color::Black);
    A objA((B*)nullptr, B::Site::X);
}
```

---

```
// Class A.h

#pragma once

extern class B;

class A
{
public:
    enum class Color
    {
        Red,
        Black
    };

    B* objectB;
    B::Site site;

    A(B* pointB, B::Site site)
    {
        objectB = pointB;
        this->site = site;
    }
};
```

---

```
// Class B.h

#pragma once

extern class A;

class B
{
public:
    enum class Site
    {
        X,
        Y
    };

    A* objectA;
    A::Color color;

    B(A* pointA, A::Color color)
    {
        objectA = pointA;
        this->color = color;
    }
};
```

Comment: Циклическая цепочка требований завершенности класса (что является обязательным условием для доступа ко вложенному классу не может скомпилироваться. Ее придется разорвать.

Comment: Насколько я понял, то класс `A` описывает свойство цвета, а `B` положение в системе координат. Почему вы в таком случае просто не сделаете множественное наследование? Вы действительно вводите циклическую зависимость и при всём при этом непонятно как пользоваться классом `A` или классом `B`

Comment: @DisplayName , я упрощённо изобразил проблему. Наименования классов и перечислений - чисто случайное название.

Comment: @Micronik а с какой ошибкой хоть падает?

Comment: @DisplayName Он их генерирует в большом количестве https://imgur.com/CO7BuWR

Comment: Сейчас попробую воспроизвести у себя. Ситуация интересная

Comment: @DisplayName видимо она обычная. Он просто не знает о существовании B::Site

Comment: По всей видимости ничего не выйдет... Вам удаётся использовать `extern class B` как указатель в коде класса `A` потому что это допускает линковщиком, но вот когда Вы попытаетесь вызвать какой-нибудь метод из объекта класса `B` или влезть в его определение, отсюда и посыпятся ошибки. Вам придётся пересмотреть проектирование этих классов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размер объектов класса **A** зависит от реального размера типа `enum B::Site`. Вижу решение только если разделить классы **A**,**B** с родителями в которых только `enum` определения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

A_Color.h

```
#pragma once

class A_Color
{
public:
    enum class Color
    {
        Red,
        Black
    };
};
```

B_Site.h

```
#pragma once

class B_Site
{
public:
    enum class Site
    {
        X,
        Y
    };
};
```

class A.h

```
#pragma once

// error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
/*extern*/ class B;

# include "A_Color.h"
# include "B_Site.h"

class A : public A_Color
{
public:

    B* objectB;
    B_Site::Site site;

    A(B* pointB, B_Site::Site site)
    {
        objectB = pointB;
        this->site = site;
    }
};
```

Class B.h

```
#pragma once

// error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
/*extern*/ class A;

# include "A_Color.h"
# include "B_Site.h"

class B:public B_Site
{
public:

    A* objectA;
    A_Color::Color color;

    B(A* pointA, A_Color::Color color)
    {
        objectA = pointA;
        this->color = color;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c++17 main.cpp -Os -o main
#include "Class A.h"
#include "Class B.h"

int main()
{
    B objB((A*)nullptr, A::Color::Black);
    A objA((B*)nullptr, B::Site::X);
}
```